# Character encoding differs between local and remote server

Tags: javascript, json, utf-8, character-encoding

I've run into a problem with character encoding. I'm using D3.js to load a json file. Some of the rows contain characters such as å, ä, and ö. These are rendered as � in the browser, **but only** when uploaded to my webhost. On the local server, it all works fine.

I've tried all thinkable encodings of the files, but nothing helps. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Are your files being served with the correct charset in the Content-Type header?

Comment: Sorry I missed your comment. The problem is solved as per below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, rule out the files being corrupted during the upload process. Make sure that the json files on the server are identical to the files you are uploading. A round-trip test is a good tool for this. (FTP the file(s) back from the server and check that it's identical to what you started with. If you're using a simple-minded FTP client on a Windows machine (or if your server is Windows), make sure to use binary transfer mode.)

Second, check the headers on the files from the server. The `Content-type` header should specify `application/json` as the media type. According to [RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt), JSON files must be encoded in some Unicode encoding. The default is UTF-8, but it could be UTF-16 (LE, BE, or with a byte order mark). Make sure that if the header specifies an encoding that it is correct. (In particular, it should match the encoding that you used to generate the file.)

If all else fails, encode the problem characters using Unicode escape sequences (e.g., `\u00e1` for á) in the JSON text.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer, which I'm sure will help many others. In my case, changing the transfer mode to binary in FileZilla solved the problem.